# Can I search for something on Google directly from Spotlight?

Tags: macos, spotlight

Whenever I have to search for something, I have to open Safari and then type in it. Is there any way to search directly, like type it in Spotlight and press click something and Safari will open automatically and search whatever you typed in Spotlight?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if the feature exists for Spotlight.
However, [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/) is a replacement for Spotlight which does what you need and much more:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tested, but if you install [Flashlight](http://flashlight.nateparrott.com) there is a plugin for [Search on Google](http://flashlight.nateparrott.com/plugin/googlesearch).

> Add over 120 plugins to OS X's Spotlight search box. Check the weather, search the web, send an iMessage, find an emoji, and more.
>
> For OS X Yosemite. Completely open-source. No crazy installer. Uninstall with one click.

Sample Google search using Flashlight plugin:
[image: Flashlight Google search]

Comment: I'm using Flashlight and it's great. It does have the possibility to search Google and many more.

Comment: Sadly Flashlight is no longer maintained, and even the fork I'm using seems to work poorly now.

Answer (score 1):

Type it in Spotlight, and hit ⌘B. (I found this by mistake!)

Answer (score 0):

Spotlight can search your safari browsing history for webpages you have previously visited, and it can search wikipedia online for information, but without the above mentioned plugins you can't search google directly.